# How to determine a general arithmetic sequence formula for two intersecting trig function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I have equations out of two trigonometric functions. 

For example

- $\cos(4\alpha$) = -$\sin(5\alpha)$
- $\tan(0.5\alpha$) = 2 $\sin(\alpha)$

How can I determine a general arithmetic sequence formula which gives me n-th positive angle where the two trig functions intersects?

By drawing the graph I found out the intersecting points..

1. 30, 70, 110... --> 30° + n * 40
2. 0, 120, 240... --> n * 120

Whereby n starts from 0.

Is there a better way to find these arithemetic sequence formula without drawing the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos4\alpha=-\sin5\alpha=\cos\left(90^\circ+5\alpha\right)$$

$$\iff4\alpha=360^\circ m\pm\left(90^\circ+5\alpha\right)$$ where $m$ is any integer

Consider '+', '-' sign one by one.

---

For the second one use $$\sin2y=\frac{2\tan y}{1+\tan^2y}$$

Comment: Seems complicated.. Could you please explain me how you've come up with this solution?

Comment: @kk-dev11, Taking '-' sign, $$9\alpha=90^\circ(4m-1)\iff\alpha=10^\circ(4m-1) $$  etc.

Comment: I see. Now I understand the final solution. What was the idea behind putting m into this cos4α=−sin5α=cos(90∘+5α) ?

Comment: @kk-dev11, Have you heard of general solution of Trig equation ?

Comment: No.. I am afraid I haven't had this yet..

Comment: @kk-dev11,  http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Trig/TrigGenSol.htm  and $$\cos(90^\circ+y)=-\sin y?$$

Comment: The basic idea is that whenever $x$ is a solution of a trig equation, so are $x + 360^\circ$ and $x - 360^\circ;$ and therefore so are $x + 2\cdot360^\circ,$ $x - 2\cdot360^\circ,$ $x + 3\cdot360^\circ,$ and so forth.